# Scaling/ normalising in cross validation

Tags: cross-validation

I have one input variable which I am using to predict one output variable.

To do this I am performing a locally linear regression, and part of this involves choosing a bandwidth parameter (which I am using LOOCV to do).

When fitting the model/ using it to predict, should I be scaling the input/ output variables? If so, should I scale them based only on the points in the training set? If so, how should I then scale each single point I use to predict? Would this differ depending on which error/ loss function I'm using?

If scaling is appropriate, what type of scaling is usually performed? Do I standardise ((X-mu)/std), or normalise to a unit vector, or something involving minimums and maximums. Any advice/ resources to look at would be appreciated.

Edit: The main reason for me asking is to do with Huber's loss function. I have typically seen values like 1.35 and 0.5 recommended to use for $\delta$. However, my outputs are several orders of magnitude larger. Do I need to scale my outputs in some way before putting them into HUber's loss function?

Comment: With one one input variable and one output variable, you do not need to scale for regression. (Scaling is usually for comparing incomparable input variables).  If you do scale, you should do so in the training set alone, and remember what you did (subtracting and dividing by which numbers) so as to do the same with the test set. (This is equivalent to using all the available data for training and then testing on future new data).

Comment: @Henry Thank you - that's very helpful. I've added an extra more specific part to my question - could you have a look and answer if you know the answer? Thank you!

Comment: If you are using a Huber loss function then you may be concerned about balancing possibility of outliers against losing informative small scale information.  Typically $\delta$ is of the order of magnitude of a standard deviation or the median absolute difference from the median.  But precise figures like $1.35$ are based on knowing the distribution is Gaussian with no spurious extreme values, and if you thought that then you would not be using a Huber loss function